# Error when redirecting data to file

Tags: perl, file, line, handler

Frequently [not always] when i run procedure define a file handler i get strange error on internal function which i dont understand how to debug.
In My PERL code i have the following line [111]:
***open V_FILE_SEC, ">>$file/V_$file$dir.csvT" or die $!;***

And when i am operating the script [>myscript.pl DPX_*] i get:

"No such file or directory at myscript.pl line 111,  line 18004."

What is the meaning of line 18004? How to start debug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [`perldoc -f die`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#die-LIST):

> If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline, the current script line number and **input line number (if any)** are also printed, and a newline is supplied. [*Emphasis added*]

The "input line number" is the value in [`$.`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#INPUT_LINE_NUMBER), roughly the number of lines of input you have read from the most recent filehandle you accessed.

In your case, you could use to look at your program input and see if there is anything unusual around line 18004 that your program wasn't expecting.

Comment: Or since the argument to your script is `DPX_*`, the trouble could come from line ~18004 of any of the input files, or on the 18000th line of the concatenation of all your input.

Comment: Thanks! i have only 1500 lines, my script fails in line 111 and 18004 ?! deferentially it goes to some other code below which i dont handle. i am manipulating large data files from many libraries starts with DPX_... Maybe there is a specific module to gain better performance with easier maintenance?